# Как объединить 8 столбцов в 1 через символ в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Необходимо объединить 8 столбцов с разным текстом, в 1 столбец через ;
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате должно получиться:
ученик;ученик
студент;учитель
репетитор
ученик;студент
Т.е. игнорируя пустые значения

Comment: Select concat(coalesce(a, ''),,';'coalesce(b, ''),..)

Comment: при таком условии, если два или более столбцов пустые в результате получается: ученик;;;ученик;;;;

Comment: Да у вас ещё и строки объединять не только столбцы

Comment: только столбцы, их всего восемь и в каждом заполнено может быть все 8 значений, а может быть 2 или 3, вот нужно заполненные объединить, а пустые проигнорировать

Comment: Тогда проще concat(coalesce(a||';', ''),coalesce(b||';', ''),..)

Comment: большое вам спасибо) все получилось

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
 trim(regexp_replace(format('%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s',a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h),'(,+)',',','g'), ',')
from t;
```

**Пояснения:**

Сначала создадим комбинированную строку, заполняя шаблон:

```
format('%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s',a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
```

Затем заменим любую последовательность запятых одной запятой:

```
regexp_replace(_str, '(,+)', ',', 'g')`
```

И в финале удалим запятые из начала и конца строки:

```
trim(_str, ',')
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Большое спасибо.

Comment: [One of the most difficult problems to overcome was that of language differences. To alleviate this problem as much as possible, the Americans learned Russian and the Russians learned English. **It was found that the best scenario was for the Russians to speak English and for the Americans to speak Russian.**](https://history.nasa.gov/apollo/apsoyhist.html)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Yes, I agree. I could write an answer in Russian, most probably with errors. However I want to be respectful to the community and therefore not write in bad language.

Comment: an explanation in "bad language" is better than no explanation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так

```
Select 
      concat(coalesce(a||';', ''),coalesce(b||';', ''),..)
       ... 
From table
```